# Составить программу вычисления суммы либо произведения (вложенные циклы)

Tags: java, математика

Составить программу вычисления суммы либо произведения (вложенные циклы).

[image: Условие]

Не могу понять логику работы с этой задачей. X = 1; a = 0. Посчитало выражение в скобках = n1; потом a = 0,2 и считает равно n2. А что между n1 и n2 делается? + или -? Подскажите плз.

```
    double part = 0;
    for (double i = 1; i <= 6 ; i++) {
        for (double j = 0; j <=2 ; j+=0.2) {
            part += pow(7,j)-cos(i);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(part);
```

Но тест кейсы не проходит, ждет ответ 2756...

Answer (score 1):

Если б это был С++, то

```
for(double a = 0; a <= 2.001; a += 0.2) {
    double sum = pow(7,a)*6;
    for(int k = 1; k <=6; ++k)
        sum -= cos(k)

    // Вывод значений a и sum - как там в Яве?

    }
```

Comment: `sum -= cos(k);`

Comment: @Igor Да, конечно, спасибо.